# Non full rank differential and holes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be a smooth and $n$ dimensional compact manifold with boundary and $B_n$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Consider the differentiable map $f:A \rightarrow B_n$, and its differential $df_p:T_pA \rightarrow T_{f(p)}B_n$

My question is: if $df_p$ has full rank for every $p \in A$, except only on isolated points, the space $A$ must be homeomorphic to $B_n$  with $n$-dimensional holes inside?

Comment: Thanks, I will change the statement of the question

Comment: Let's be precise, are you asking if $A$ is homeomorphic to $B_n \setminus X$ where $X$ is a disjoint union of balls inside $B_n$?

Comment: Can $A$ have boundary? (Your question on $B_n$ with holes indicates that it can). Then as I said before, any $n$-manifold with boundary, smoothly embedded into $B_n$, is a counter-example. A thickened knot, for example.

Comment: Yes, A has boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $n$-dimensional compact manifold with boundary that can be embedded into $B_n$, is a counter-example; the embedding $f$ has no critical points at all. Take, for instance, a thick circle (that is, a closed neighborhood of a circle in $B_n$), or any thickened $k$-manifold without boundary for $k<n$ embedded in $B_n$.

(For compact $n$-manifolds without boundary (they can never be embedded into $B_n$) the question seems harder.)